# NHibernate with sql Server 2008 dialect don't support variable limits

Tags: mvc, nhibernate

Не могу сделать выборку mvc3. Exception : Dialect does not support variable limits.

```
var query = _shopRepository.Get<IProduct>().Query();
if (model.Page > 0 && model.Size > 0)
{
    query = query.Skip((model.Page - 1)*model.Size);
}
query = query.Take(model.Size);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Нашел. В hibernate.cfg.xml <property name="dialect"> NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
    </property>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь MsSqlCe40Dialect